# Unable to add new iOS bundle identifier to my app - LinkedIn

Tags: ios, swift, linkedin-api, bundle-identifier

I have registered my app to LinkedIn to verify the user through LinkedIn. I've also added some iOS bundle identifiers to it and it was working fine.

But from last few days, when I try to add a new bundle identifier and save it the error appears. The error states, 'Your changes could not be saved right now, please try again'.

I think this issue is with LinkedIn API.

How can I add my new bundle identifier to my registered app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the string that you are trying to change. It worked in our case.